# Repeat/repeated offender

Tags: collocation, legalese

In legal talk, specifically regarding criminals, it is standard usage to call someone who has broken the law several times a "repeat offender."  However, I don't understand why such a person wouldn't be called a "repeated offender."   Indeed, I have found somewources that use "repeated offender," but these sources appeared to be English-language newspapers from non-anglophone countries, so I don't find them to be reliable examples.

So, two questions: why "repeat" and not "repeated offender"?--in what other collocations is "repeat" used adjectivally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compound noun ***repeat offender*** is recognised by the OED, as the below extract will confirm.

Nonetheless to describe someone as a "repeated offender" would also be idiomatic. But it would have a less-official sense, and be used more loosely, in conjecture, or to make a point.

***Repeat offender*** is, *inter alia* an official categorisation of prisoners and people charged with crimes.

> b. Forming compounds denoting a person who does something (implied by
>   the second element) again or repeatedly, as repeat customer, repeat
>   offender, repeat viewer, repeat visitor, etc.
>
> 1906   Pearson's Mag. July 108/2   It is your ‘repeat’ customers that
>   make your business profitable.
>
> 1940   Science 16 Aug. 143/2   An immense public, equivalent
>   numerically—not allowing for repeat visitors—to approximately four per
>   cent. of the total population of the entire nation.
>
> 1952   F. Pohl & C. M. Kornbluth in Galaxy June 33/2   Survey the
>   book-buyers, the repeat-viewers of O' Shea's TV shows.
>
> 1978   Washington Post 8 Aug. c4/5   Many juveniles, he adds, are
>   repeat offenders, ‘recycled’ through the system.
>
> 1986   A. Isserman Population Change & Econ. i. 16   Demographers have
>   noted that a large proportion of migrants are repeat migrants or
>   return migrants. 1993   Parents June 65/4 (heading)    About 80% of
>   repeat miscarriers suffer from polycystic ovary syndrome.
>
> 2003   Philadelphia Inquirer 11 July a14/2   Judges could be ordering
>   repeat offenders to equip their vehicles with ignition switches that
>   work only when a driver proves his or her sobriety by blowing into a
>   tube.

Comment: There's 'repeat prescription' as well.

Answer (score 2):

The offender *repeats* their offences. It is not the offender who is 
*being repeated*.